# Loop through JSON array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a JSON array which is returned from my PHP ajax call. I need to loop through it and display all the information. I can  not seem to get a method working. I am used to using the foreach key => value, in PHP but that doesn't seem to be an option here.

my array is

```
[{"Type":"Person","Durable":"Durable","Url":"test.com"},
{"Type":"Person","Durable":"Durable","Url":"test2.com"},
{"Type":"Person","Durable":"Durable","Url":"test3.com"},
{"Type":"Person","Durable":"Durable","Url":"test4.com"},
{"Type":"Location","Durable":"Durable","Url":"test5.com"},
{"Type":"Phone","Durable":"Durable","Url":"test6.com"}]
```

The length of the array changes every time it is not always 6 items. 
And the loop is going to go in my success handler. I just need help on how to access the data.

```
success: function(data){

}
```

Comment: `for (var i in data) { ... }` should work.  You would reference an array item with `data[i]`

Comment: I know that it is, but everywhere else I saw I found crazy amount of different ways and i couldnt get any to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple loop statement:

```
   success: function(data){
    var i, l;
    for (i = 0, l = data.length; i < l; i++) { 
        // access the object: data[i]
        console.log(data[i]);
    }
  }
```

This is the most effiecient way.

Comment: *This is the most effiecient way* - based on what?

Comment: And why do you use two variables in your `for` loop?

Comment: `l` is defined only once. If you done something like `data.length` withn the evaulation, it is computed each time

Comment: What if i needed to display the data in a special location. How could i access it like data[Type] as a variable

Comment: you just do `data[i].Type` .. `data[i].Durable` .. etc.. This solution is a bit faster than `forEach` and also works on older browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You can just loop through the array:

```
success: function(data){
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { 
    var obj = data[i];
    var type = obj.Type;
    var durable = obj.Durable;
    var url = obj.Url;
    // do work
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the array prototype `forEach`:

```
data.forEach(function(item) {
    var type = item["Type"];
    var durable = item["Durable"];
    /*...*/
});
```

Comment: `forEach` is not supported natively on some older browsers like IE8

Comment: This is what I need to access the data how i want, thank you so much!